# How are objects stored in the memory in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, memory

I was wondering - how are objects stored int the memory?
I already know that there's a reference (like a pointer) that is an int value containing the place in the memory where that object is stored - but how exactly is it stored?
Lets say I have `ClassC` that has `int a, char b, long c, float d` and `short e` - I know how each is stored each have their own set of bit but the amount of bits in each different - so how exactly does C# knows which bits should it access when I write `OBJ.c` or `OBJ.b` ?
Is it somewhat possible to convert a whole (nonstatic) object to an array of bytes\bit AND back?
OBVIOUSLY - If there's something like `ClassC.TcpListener tcp` - it's a reference and stored as an `int` (? Atleast it has the same size in bytes) - but still, how can it different between an `int` and a pointer?

Comment: "but how exactly is it stored?" - Can you clarify exactly what you are looking for here? Heap vs Stack? Endieness? Something else?

Comment: Note that most answers here will be an implementation detail. A reference is largely intended to be opaque - even if it does happen to be a pointer in most cases, it isn't *required* to be. Also; on x64 references are 64-bit, not 32 ("int")

Comment: Also, ECMA-335 would give you a full answer to this. It is a bit dry, of course.

Comment: I mean - if I open my RAM at the location that `Object A` is stored - what will I see ? (in bits of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, this isn't something you need to care about unless you're P/Invoking a C library.

> so how exactly does C# knows which bits should it access when I write
>   OBJ.c or OBJ.b ?

It depends on the [StructLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) of the object.  There are two possible [LayoutKind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx)s.

The default is Sequential, where fields are stored in the same order they are declared, [aligned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack.aspx) appropriately.  By default, a `struct` containing your five fields would be stored as:

- offset 0-3: `int a`
- offset 4-5: `char b`
- offset 6-7: padding
- offset 8-15: `long c`
- offset 16-19: `float d`
- offset 20-21: `short e`

A `class` may have a slightly different layout due to vtable pointers, garbage collector metadata, etc.  I'm not sure exactly how it works.

The other LayoutKind is Explicit, where you specify the field offsets explicitly.

> Is it somewhat possible to convert a whole (nonstatic) object to an array of bytes\bit AND back?

Yes, the [Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) class will let you do this.  See [StructureToPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx) and [PtrToStructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ex8z62.aspx).

> it's a reference and stored as an `int`

Pointers are not stored as `int`s.  That wouldn't work on 64-bit systems.  [IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is used instead.

> but still, how can it different between an int and a pointer?

At which level?  C#?  CIL?  Machine language?

Comment: "StructLayout of the object" seems somewhat of an oxymoron...

Comment: `Marshal` class won't let you look at the bytes as they are in memory, at least not always. What it does is to translate it into a form suitable for unmanaged code. Oftentimes, that translation doesn't do anything, but not always.

Answer (score 2):

C# actually doesn't know where to access the members in the object. It's the JIT compiler that decides the layout of the objects.

It's possible to add attributes for the members so that the JIT compiler places the members in a specific way, which would make it possible to access all the members as a memory block, but it's rarely worth the effort.

Note: A pointer is 32 bits (int) on a 32 bit system and 64 bits (long) on a 64 bit system.

Comment: So that's why 64bit systems takes a bunch of memory >.<